# 3D rotation with wrong rotation axises

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, rotation, rubiks-cube

i am having a small problem using 3d rotation matrices to implement a rubiks cube simulator. my problem is that, when trying to rotate my cube around the global x and y axis (in 3d), i end up rotating around
the global x axis and cube's y axis. for example, take the next picture as the starting point: [the original position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzrTU.png)

take the next picture as an example for what happens when i try to rotate around the y axis by moving mouse to the left: [incorrectly rotating around the cube's y axis instead of the global y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwbPa.png)

and the next picture as an example for what happens when i try to rotate around the x axis by moving mouse down: [correctly rotating around the global x axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI0b5.png)

here you can see the code that i have used to perform the rotation:

```
from math import cos,sin
import numpy as np
def rotate(mat,xangle,yangle,zangle):  #these angles are by how much i want to rotate around a certain                   axis (in radians)
    xrotation_matrix = np.matrix([[1,0,0],
                                  [0,cos(xangle),-sin(xangle)],
                                  [0,sin(xangle),cos(xangle)]])
    yrotation_matrix = np.matrix([[cos(yangle),0,sin(yangle)],
                                  [0,1,0],
                                  [-sin(yangle),0,cos(yangle)]])
    zrotation_matrix = np.matrix([[cos(zangle),-sin(zangle),0],
                                  [sin(zangle),cos(zangle),0],
                                  [0,0,1]])
    rotated3d = np.dot(zrotation_matrix,mat.reshape((3,1)))  #mat is a point in the form np.matrix([x,y,z])
    rotated3d = np.dot(yrotation_matrix,rotated3d)
    rotated3d = np.dot(xrotation_matrix,rotated3d)
    return rotated3d
```

for extra context (although slightly unnecessary) on how the code works, here is how i calculate how to get the rotation angles:

```
def get_full_turn(self,mousepos):
    xchange = mousepos[0]-self.startdrag[0]
    ychange = mousepos[1]-self.startdrag[1]
    self.xangle -= self.xadding
    self.yangle -= self.yadding
    self.xadding = ychange/100
    self.yadding = xchange/100
    self.xangle += self.xadding
    self.yangle += self.yadding
```

How can i make the cube rotate around the global x and global y axis so i can properly rotate it?
(pls explain very simply as i am just a passionate, but very new A-level student)

so far i have tried reversing the order of multiplicaiton with rotation matrices (some website showed something similar as a solution), but very similar results show (only 1 axis is rotated around a global axis, yet the others around the current axis).

for extra info if my wording is confusing, i have been searching for the type of rotation, and it seems to be known as an ‘extrinsic’ rotation (if i am not worngly midtaken)

also, the question that i am suppososed to be duplicating has 1 answer. and that answer does not go over how these matrices work and does not go over the way to rotate the FULL cube, as well as the smaller parts, which i have already done.

Answer (score 0):

Second image is not so informative, but I think that the problem is that you have your cube's center not in the `(0, 0, 0)` position.
Rotation matrices rotate vetrices relative to `(0, 0, 0)` vertex.

More informative [example](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/2DRotationUsingMatrices/) from wolfram alpha (but only for 2D).

If it is a problem, the solution is shift matrix. First of all, you shift your cube to the position with matrix M_shify, where it has it's center in `(0, 0, 0)`. Then rotate with matrices. And after that use reverse shift matrix (shift parameters multiplied by -1)

Also, it is prefered to use matmul operator `@` for matrix multiplying.

For 2D matrices [numpy.dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) is equivalent for matmul operator:

```
rotated3d = np.dot(zrotation_matrix,mat.reshape((3,1)))
    rotated3d = np.dot(yrotation_matrix,rotated3d)
    rotated3d = np.dot(xrotation_matrix,rotated3d)
```

is equivalent to

```
rotated3d = zrotation_matrix @ yrotation_matrix @ xrotation_matrix @ rotated3d
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i do rotate around the origin, and then i multiply and scale it up, then adding x to place it onto the screen

Comment: i will also change the program to use matmul,

Comment: can you provide more information then, please? 1. Position of cube's vertices. 2. Position of colors. Also, did you test mouse angle outputs?